# Strip 2m characters from string in Python

Tags: python, strip

I'm trying to remove the "`m2`" characters from a string using python. This is the code i'm using right now. Unfortunately it appears to do nothing to the string.

Typically the string i would like to strip looks as follow; `502m2`, `3m2`....

```
if "m2" in messageContent:
   messageContent = messageContent.translate(None, 'm2')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str.translate()` is not the correct tool here; you are removing all `m` and all `2` characters regardless of their context.

If you need to remove the literal text `'m2'`, just use [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

```
messageContent = messageContent.replace('m2', '')
```

You don't even need to test first; `str.replace()` will return the string unchanged if there are no instances of the  literal text present:

```
>>> '502m2, 3m2'.replace('m2', '')
'502, 3'
>>> 'The quick brown fox'.replace('m2', '')
'The quick brown fox'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [str.replace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)
*Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring old replaced by new. If the optional argument count is given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.*

```
s = "502m2, 3m2"
print s.replace("m2","")
502, 3
```